# Add more items into seeds.rb in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

My application has Categories and Subcategories,
to add a **category** i type in `db/seeds.rb` this code 
`category = Category.create!(name:  "Video and animation") #it works` and

for **subcategory** i type `subcategory = Subcategory.create!(name:  "Intro", "Animation & 3D", "Editing and Post Production", "Other" ) #it doesn't work`

and then to assign subcategory to category i type in the end `category.subcategories << subcategory`

The problem occurs when i create a **subcategory** with more names as in the code above,what am i doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: When i create a subcategory with the code above,it gives an error.

Comment: what is the error message you see ?

Comment: so you have a column :name, and you assign it "Intro". But what are the rest of it supposed to be? Post your schema.

Comment: `/home/action/workspace/sharebox/db/seeds.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input                                                                                                                  
... "post production","Editing and Post Production", "Other" ) ` ,i did try to put and **end** as end of input it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`@category = Category.create!(name:  "Video and animation")`

`["Intro", "Animation & 3D", "Editing and Post Production", "Other"].each do |name|`

`@subcategory = Subcategory.create!(name: name, category_id: @category.id)`

`end`

Comment: It works really well,how would you show the subcategories in the views.Any advice? thank you!.

Comment: i tried `<% Subcategory.all.each do |subcategory| %>
  <%= link_to subcategory.name, gigs_path(subcategory: subcategory.name) %>
<% end %>` , but it shows all the products,from all the subcategories,when i need to show the products  just from one specific subcategory.

Comment: use <% (Subcategory.where(:name=>''Intro")).each do |subcategory| %>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a relation `subcategory belongs_to category`, with subcategory table including `category_id` field:

```
category = Category.create!(name:  "Video and animation") 
["Intro", "Animation & 3D", "Editing and Post Production", "Other"].each do |name|
  subcategory = Subcategory.create!(name: name, category: category)
end
```

Comment: There is no need to assign to `subcategory` inside the loop, since it won't be available outside its scope anyway. (Even if it was, it would contain only the last `Subcategory`.) If he needs the subcategories later, he is better off doing: `subcategories = [...].map { |name| Subcategory.create!(name: name, category: category) }`.

Comment: **Uday kumar das** answer worked really well for me,but how would you show the subcategories in the views.i tried `<% Subcategory.all.each do |subcategory| %> <%= link_to subcategory.name, gigs_path(subcategory: subcategory.name) %> <% end %>`  ,and it shows all my 4 subcategories as needed,but when i click on one of them,for example on "Animation and 3D" it shows other products from other subcategories as well.

Comment: You need to edit your `gigs_controller#index` method. Difficult to say without seeing the code but you should have there something along the lines of `subcategory = Subcategory.find_by(name: params[:subcategory]); @products = subcategory.products`. In the view you'd then use `@products.each` instead of `Product.all.each`

Comment: here is the link to the full question wit the code,thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559892/cant-display-my-category-and-subcategory-in-the-views-rails-4/29560106#29560106