# Can't display my category and subcategory in the views Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

My website has Categories and subcategories,here is what i have in my seeds.rb,there i create a main category called "Video and animation",and 4 subcategories,than i assign the subcategories to the main category.

```
@category = Category.create!(name:  "Video and animation")

["Intro", "Animation & 3D", "Editing and Post Production", "Other"].each do |name|

@subcategory = Subcategory.create!(name: name, category_id: @category.id)

end
```

It works well,in my rails console i see that everything works,the category_id for the added products changes to a number(integer as it should).

**Question:** How do i show the category in my views,so when someone clicks on that he gets all the products of that category.
And how do i show all the subcategories following the same principle.
Here is what i tried to put into my views

```
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, gigs_path(category: category.name) %>
<% end %>
<% Subcategory.all.each do |subcategory| %>
  <%= link_to subcategory.name, gigs_path(subcategory: subcategory.name) %>
<% end %>
```

The weird thing is that when i put in my product controller 
this

```
def index
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])
      @gigs = Gig.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
      @subcategory_id = Subcategory.find_by(name: params[:subcategory])
      @gigs = Gig.where(subcategory_id: @subcategory_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

It shows just the required subcategories,as i want,but the main category remains empty.
and if i put instead this into my controller

```
def index
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])
      @subcategory_id = Subcategory.find_by(name: params[:subcategory])
      @gigs = Gig.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

The main category works,as required,but the subcategories remain empty.

**Note:** In both cases,in the views,before anyone clicks on anything,i see the proper category and subcategories displayed.

Here is what i have in each of the 3 models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subcategory
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

*Thank you for your time.*

Comment: why don't you use, `Category` `has_may` relationship and `sub_category` will `belongs_to` `category`. please go through this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: can you specify views and controller names

Comment: Its really hard to explain,please give me your bitbucket username,i will send an invitation,so you can take a look,thank very much.

Comment: my bitbucket id is `Sontya`.

Comment: you have two links in view `category` and other is `subcategory` which one you are clicking, because at a time you can click only one link right? so it will send category.name or subcategory.name. So you have to change the `index` method accordingly `if(params[:category])` find for category `elsif (params[:subcategory])` find for subcategory

Comment: glad it worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In controller action**

```
@categories = Category.includes(:subcategories)
```

**Add In views**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
     <%= link_to category.name, gigs_path(category: category.name) %>
     <% category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
          <%= link_to subcategory.name, gigs_path(subcategory: subcategory.name) %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Change your index method in controller**

```
def index
    if params[:category]
        c_id = Category.find(name: params[:category])
        @gigs = Gig.where(category_id: c_id).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:subcategory]    
        subc_id = Subcategory.find(name: params[:subcategory])
        @gigs = Gig.where(subcategory_id: subc_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end    
end
```

Comment: it doesn't answer my question,i have all the relationships in place,like has_many,and belongs_to,everything works fine,but as i said i can't display it in the views.In the method described by me above,as you see i get whether the category shows up,or just the subcategories.Please read my question again,thank you for the effort,appreciate that!.

Comment: I got your question, you are not using relationships properly, see my updated answer

Comment: i added my current models,and you are right,but i already have them in place.I tried your Edit part and now when i click on the main category it shows every product i have from this category,and when i click on a random subcategory it shows the same result,when it should show just the product from the specific subcategory.